Custom Module not found Android Dependencies (Flutter Plugin)
I have been trying to install one particular custom android module for almost a day now. I have tried different resources (including ChatGPT) but it seems I am probably missing something. Please I would appreciate any effort I can get. Thank you.
Below is the directory. The custom module is the MHUI folder.

The MHUI plugin gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {

    compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation "com.alibaba:fastjson:1.1.70.android"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
    implementation'com.lzy.net:okgo:3.0.4'

    api files('libs/MHSDK-2.4.5.aar')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

The Android Folder Build.gradle:
group 'com.meihu.phonebeauty'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':mhui').file('libs')
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace 'com.meihu.phonebeauty'
    }

    compileSdk 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compileOnly rootProject.findProject(":mhui")
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.0.0'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            testLogging {
               events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
               outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
               showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
}

My AndroidFolder/Settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'mh_plugin'

include ':mhui'

The Error Messages:

